# Which functions should I use to work with an XDF file on HDFS?

Tags: r, hadoop, revolution-r

I have an .xdf file on an HDFS cluster which is around 10 GB having nearly 70 columns. I want to read it into a R object so that I could perform some transformation and manipulation. I tried to Google about it and come around with two functions:

```
rxReadXdf

rxXdfToDataFrame
```

Could any one tell me the preferred function for this as I want to read data & perform the transformation in parallel on each node of the cluster?

Also if I read and perform transformation in chunks, do I have to merge the output of each chunks?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers,
Amit

Comment: Also if I read the data in chunks how would I decide the number of chunks dynamically as the data size keeps on varing

Answer (score 2):

Note that `rxReadXdf` and `rxXdfToDataFrame` have different arguments and do slightly different things:

- `rxReadXdf` has a numRows argument, so use this if you want to read the top 1000 (say) rows of the dataset
- `rxXdfToDataFrame` supports [rxTransforms](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RevoScaleR/functions/rxTransform), so use this if you want to manipulate your data in addition to reading it
- `rxXdfToDataFrame` also has the maxRowsByCols argument, which is another way of capping the size of the input

So in your case, you want to use `rxXdfToDataFrame` since you're transforming the data in addition to reading it. `rxReadXdf` is a bit faster in the local compute context if you just want to read the data (no transforms). This is probably also true for HDFS, but I haven’t checked this.

However, are you sure that you want to read the data into a data frame? You can use `rxDataStep` to run (almost) arbitrary R code on an xdf file, while still leaving your data in that format. See the linked documentation page for how to use the transforms arguments.